# Using component vs partial for 'site header' in ember.js

Tags: ember.js, ember.js-2

This is more of a design/best practice question, in `Ember 2.x`

I am building a new ember web app, and for the site's header, I created a separate component, `site-header` and included that in the application.hbs as follows.

application.hbs

```
{{site-header}}
{{outlet}}
```

I am trying to find out, if *using a partial instead of a component might be a better choice*, for the following reasons:

This component, `site-header`...

- is used only in `application.hbs`
- doesn't maintain any state
- has no `actions` associated with it (just some links to change the `route` ).

Comment: if my answer satisfied your question would you mind accepting it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would keep it as a component since Ember is moving towards that kind of architecture.

Comment: Always bet on components.